# How to auto populate specific Google Form fields, based on dropdown choice

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I use Google Forms regularly at work, and I think they are awesome, especially since I am a total newbie with coding. With a few good plugins for Forms and Sheets, I am able to generate contracts, invoices, and so on very easily, based on document templates.

To keep it short, here is my request:

1. I have a form, where I input the customer's details, and upon submission, an addon generates a gdoc, based on a template. Al working great so far. My problem is that we are generating many different documents for a single customer, so it becomes a repetitive and very time-consuming task, considering that I have 15-20 different input fields for a customer, plus specific input fields for each different document.
2. The first input filed in my form is `"Customer Name"` and I have managed to create a dynamic dropdown list, that takes it's information from a specific column in a Google Sheet.
3. My request: how could I auto populate *specific* input fields in my Google Form, so that, based on my dropdown choice, the auto completed information will match the corresponding row present in the Google Sheet.

I have attached 2 images for easier understanding:

[image: Form Example]
[image: Sheet Example]

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do this with a simple vlookup:

note: I also always wrap my functions with and if statement that checks if there is text  in the first field, so try:

pretend that your dynamic customer name is in cell A1:

customer vat formula -

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1),VLOOKUP(A1,'Parteneri'!A:C,2,FALSE),)
```

customer city formula -

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1),VLOOKUP(A1,'Parteneri'!A:C,3,FALSE),)
```

Comment: I am a total stranger to coding,  but isn't that a built in Microsoft Excel function? Is that something to be integrated in a Google Forms add on?

Comment: @HANESBLANCTrading Google Sheets has several functions that are similar to MS Excel functions.

Comment: this wouldn't help to pre-populate a form field - which is what I understand is the request